# Missing Request Inspector info:Twilio-AWS Lex integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, twilio

Twilio connects to AWS Lex, fetches the response, but the 'Request Inspector' for Twilio says 'There were no HTTP Requests logged for this event'.

Why isn't the HTTP POST request logged?

[screenshot: Twilio UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRBd1.png)

Comment: Hello, I'd like to help but I am going to need a lot more detail than this. Can you share some code and some context for your issue please?

Comment: Thanks. I created a chatbot using AWS Lex, which works well with the Facebook messenger. On integrating with Twilio, it does work, I get the responses but the HTTP requests do not get logged. I have followed the steps outlined here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/twilio-bot-association.html#twilio-bot-assoc-create-assoc

Comment: Hey, I am still not sure what you mean regarding the requests. You have a Lex bot set up and integrated with Twilio. You have set the request URL for SMS to the Lex bot's URL. You send a message to your Twilio number. Where are you looking at this request inspector? In this case, Twilio is making a request to AWS, to your Lex bot, not receiving POST requests.

Comment: I can provide you the screenshots for Twilio request and response. Under the HTTP requests section, no information is logged. I need to work with the request/response headers.

Comment: Please do update your question with those screenshots.

Comment: @phinash Updated!

Comment: It's not a good answer right now, but it seems that we are not storing the data for successful HTTP requests, only those that ended in error for debugging purposes. I've added this question to an internal ticket, so maybe this will change in the future.

Comment: @philnash Is there any way to capture the HTTP request data? I need it in my application. Thanks!

Comment: This HTTP request is one between Lex and Twilio. If you want to broker messages in between Lex and Twilio then you will either need to use the  [AWS Lambda integration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/using-lambda.html) to take action based on messages or interact as the intermediary between Lex and Twilio, using [the API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_Operations.html) to send Lex messages and get responses.

Comment: In each case, the user input is being sent by Twilio, which then invokes an intent in AWS Lambda, and further navigates to the Lambda function. AWS Lambda is integrated with Lex to process the user input, but Lex is the one in contact with the user/channel, Twilio in this case. Not sure how Lex can pass HTTP request data to Lambda (haven't encountered any such parameter)

Comment: You showed me a screenshot of a message that had been sent by Twilio to a user, presumably initiated by Lex through your connected Twilio channel. I think my point here is that the HTTP data is not what you are looking for, but you can access all the rest of the data about the request and response that you like within Lex and Lambda. What do you think you need the HTTP request itself for?

Comment: @philnash Thank you. I want to make use of geolocation through Twilio. When a user sends a request to Lex via Twilio, I want to capture that location. And I suppose that can be incorporated in the HTTP request. Not sure about it. Suggestions?

Comment: Oh, ok. You showed me a screenshot of Lex sending a message, but you want the details of the incoming message. From my reading around Lex's documentation, it doesn't appear to deal with the arbitrary options that the Twilio HTTP request sends to a webhook endpoint. It appears it might be best for you to setup your own webhook to receive Twilio events, then converse with Lex via [the Lex API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/API_Operations.html).

Comment: Thank you. This idea seems good. Will look into it.